# Unexpected behavior using the << operator into a specific index in an Array

Tags: arrays, ruby

If I use the shovel operator normally to append an element into an array, then I can expect the following:

```
stack  = [6,7]
result = stack << 9
```

And `result` is now `[6,7,9]`

However, if I have:

```
overflow = [6,7]
result   = overflow[1] << 3
```

Then `result` is now `56`

I've tried lots of different numbers and combinations, but nothing seems consistent. Any ideas on what's happening?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-3C-3C

Comment: For (approximately!) the desired behaviour: `Array#insert`. E.g. `overflow.insert(1, 3)` inserts `3` between indexes `0` and `1`, with following elements re-indexed. This means it can do its own kind of append too: `overflow.insert(overflow.size, 3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing

```
stack  = [6,7]
result = stack << 9
```

You are actually appending the element `9` to the array `stack` at the end. That is why you get the modified array. But when you use

```
overflow = [6,7]
result   = overflow[1] << 3
```

You are actually first getting the `1th` element from the array and shifting the bit position to the left by `3` positions.

Answer (score 2):

`<<` is *also* the [left bit shift operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-3C-3C).

Really you are saying

```
result = 7 << 3
```

which evaluates to 56.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: That makes sense! I forgot about the << being a bitwise operator too. This little curiosity was driving me nuts. Thx for the answer.